# AX 2009 - TFS - Issue with Label File

Tags: tfs, label, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We have implemented TFS for Dynamics AX 2009 as our version control system. Everything is going great with the power of TFS except for that of label files. The problem we are facing is when multiple developers check out the label file. In such cases when the developers check-in their changes are always overridden with the last developers changes.

e.g.
Dev A and Dev B checkout the same label file
Dev A modifies label id @LBL1 from "Hi there" to "Hi here"
Dev B modified label id @LBL4 from "This will work" to "Nope, that's not the case"

Dev A checks in his changes
Dev B checks in his changes

When Dev B checks in his changes, the label file will contain

@LBL1 "Hi there"

@LBL4 "Nope, that's not the case"

In the above case, TFS should have auto merged the changes for @LBL1 and made it "Hi here" which is not happening. This is working fine with all other objects than with the Label Files...

If anyone knows or has faced a similar issues, kindly shed some light if we are missing anything.

P.S. We have the Get latest on check out enabled on the source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign each developer their own @LBA, @LBB, @LBC label file.  We have had many of the same issues with TFS in 2009 and that was easiest/best solution we used.

It also provided a little bit of identity around some modules a few years later.

Lastly, labels are very simple, so you could always merge them into one if you **really** wanted to 'rebase' the labels or something.

Comment: Thank you for the information Alex. That does sound like a great idea. Currently we are doing the worst possible thing of checking-out the label files one at a time :( I will discuss the solution with the team and see if we can do something similar

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the (AX) **Team Server**? This service is mandatory to have more than one developer with TFS in AX 2009. You have more information in the following white papers:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23608

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9915

Comment: @j-a-estevan - Yes, we do have Team ID Server installed to manage the ID's.